# System ruby is not controlled by RVM, but you can use it with 'rvm automount'

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I mistakenly had two ruby version managers installed in my laptop parallelly: **rbenv** and **rvm**. When I added .rvmrc file to my project with a command to use specific ruby version and gemset name then every time when I `cd` into my project's folder, I get:

> System ruby is not controlled by RVM, but you can use it with 'rvm automount', read more: 'rvm help mount'.

I thought removing rbenv fixes the problem, so I did

```
sudo apt-get purge rbenv
```

But nothing better.

I then checked for hidden dirs in my home folder and discovered `.rbenv` directory from there. I removed it but no effect.

Then I thought reinstalling the ruby version with rvm will help, but still no effect.

I then tried doing the `rvm automount` as suggested. This gave me following output:

```
me@dell:~/apps/myproject$ rvm automount
  Warning! PATH is not properly set up, $GEM_HOME is not set.
  Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
  You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
  To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.5.0'.
  To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
  Found 'ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]' in '/usr'

  # Please enter name [ruby-2.3.3-p222]: 

  Mounting 'ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222' from '/usr' with 'bin/ruby'
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #gemset created /home/me/.rvm/gems/ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222@global
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #importing gemset /home/me/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems......................there was an error 
  installing gem rubygems-bundler
  ................
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #generating global wrappers........
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #gemset created /home/me/.rvm/gems/ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #importing gemsetfile /home/me/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
  ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 - #generating default wrappers........
```

The part where it asked for name was confusing. I also read `rvm help mount` page but didn't see anything I could use from there. The result was a new rvm gemset with ugly name `ext-ruby-2.3.3-p222 [ x86_64 ]` which still didn't fix the part where I got the initial error.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that .rvmrc file was made by hand and included a command like `rvm gemset use 2.3.3@myproject` which is obviously wrong. Probably messed up some instructions :)

Removing .rvmrc and doing

```
rvm --create use 2.3.3@myproject --rvmrc
```

fixed the problem.